# Not getting response to DocuSign webhook listener url

Tags: docusignapi

For getting envelop status, I followed these steps

1. docusign developer account, under connect, I created a connect with webhook url.
2. In code , I have given eventNotification with webhook listener url with https:// address of my application.
3. I am getting response in connect logs. But I am not getting any response in my application webhook listner .why?
   I have used Laravel code, with route
   Route::post('webhook', [TestController::class, 'webhook']);
   But I am not getting any response in function?why?

Comment: how did you deploy this? on your own server? or on some cloud provider?

Comment: On our own server . I need to set up Connect webhooks per envelope. So for webhook per envelop, do we need to enable connect from developer account? or only need to write event notification while create Envelop in docusign rest api , right?

Comment: So, in many cases your server is not accessibly over the web. There are firewalls, proxy etc. May need to confirm you can call your server the same exact way DocuSign will

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that your server (the "listener") has an https URL that is visible (callable) from the public internet. Best way to confirm this: implement a GET function at a URL such as https://your-server.com/hello. It should reply with "hello" when called. Then try entering that URL on your mobile phone.
2. Look at DocuSign's Connect error log to see what it says.
3. To assure yourself that DocuSign is sending notification messages, first use https://webhook.site to get a test webhook listener URL, and configure DocuSign to use it.
4. If you feel that the messages are being sent to your server but are not being received by your software, check your web server's logs. For example, if you're including documents in your notifications, the notifications will be very large and may exceed your web server's default configuration limits.

Comment: My https url is visible from public internet . I tried with webhook site and docusign response is coming, but still docusign respone not working with my https url.

Answer (score 0):

One issue which I have found, the response which is sent from Webhook to our own custom API, which will receive request from webhook does not match

For e.g.argument webhook sends json payload , so make sure you have same object which is supported by your api from docusign connect

// this is C# code
public async Task Post([**FromBody] JObject envelopeData**)

To test locally, you can use ngrock, which will create local server but you will be able to debug

Comment: I configured connect in docusign account and in log, response is coming correcly in json and whatever code I have written in my webook call backurl( my application url) that also showing in connect log. But it is not reflecting in my url. why? do I need to do any setting change ?

Comment: @developer2022 can u post screenshot with proper step?

Comment: You can try to use Postman and copy Json Payload from Connect Log,  then test if you are able to hit your API while posting json payload

Answer (score 0):

You can try something as below. The same worked for me.

```
if (!Request.Body.CanSeek) { Request.EnableBuffering(); } 
Request.Body.Position = 0; 
var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8); 
var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```